# Shiny app deployed with RInno doesn't show download window

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, electron

So I've deployed my Shiny application using `RInno` library. Everything was successful. The file upload works, but the downloadButton doesn't, while it works in browser. When I click the download button I can see that another window is created by the app, but it's not visible.

[Normal app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGOOu.jpg)

[App icon after I press download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ECCY.jpg)

As you can see, the bar under the icon is changed, sometimes it's two bars stacked.
It's strange to me, because the windows for upload appear normally, while this download is broken.